# Hyperlink Excel To Show And Hide Rows

Tags: excel, hyperlink, hide, show, rows

I am trying to use a hyperlink to show and hide some rows.

It seems simple enough but I don't have a clue how to fiddle with the code to hide rows.

Example If I click on " Assessments"

It should show me rows 15 : 25

If I click on "references"

It should show me 35:45

and so on and so forth

I can hide the rows with a macro, how would I re-hide them once I am done?

Also How would I hide these rows once I am done with Assessments?

Any help appreciated.

thank you

Comment: What is " Assessments"? A button? Some image? Or text in a cell? If it is a shape then you can right click on it and assign it to a macro which will show hide the rows. For the macro, I would recommend recording a macro.

Comment: Hi Its text in a cell, how would I re-hide them after I am done

Comment: You cannot hyperlink text to a macro. I would recommend using a shape or a button for this or directly running the macro from the developer toolbar